# Captcha without external API call

Tags: javascript, php, html, captcha

I am currently on a very old project we had with some friends that has been unavailable for months. I'm hosting it on my provider's free hosting service, as nobody wants to pay for a domain and hosting.

And there lies the problem : I have a contact form that I want to protect with Google's reCaptcha. I know how to make it work, I've done it before. Unfortunately, my provider forbids any call to any external ressources...

In addition, I have no access to the server, so I can't add any library or edit the settings (it would have been too easy...). The PHP version on this host is 5.1.3 (please don't yell, I know...).

So the question is: is there a captcha solution that doesn't rely on external ressources and doesn't require installing libraries?

Thanks!

Comment: Simple-php-captcha: https://github.com/claviska/simple-php-captcha

Comment: Well thanks, that works! How can I accept your answer in the comments?

Comment: No problem, made it an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**simple-php-captcha**](https://github.com/claviska/simple-php-captcha)

It allows to use custom patterns and fonts and using it is quite simple:

Demo and usage can be found [**here**](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/simple-php-captcha/). Here's the summary directly from the mentioned link:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("simple-php-captcha.php");
$_SESSION['captcha'] = simple_php_captcha();
?>
```

To **display the CAPTCHA** image, create an HTML `<img>` using `$_SESSION['captcha']['image_src']` as the `src` attribute:

To **verify the CAPTCHA** value on the next page load (or in an AJAX request), test against `$_SESSION['captcha']['code']`. You can use `strtolower()` or `strtoupper()` to perform a case-insensitive match.

**Configuration:**

```
$_SESSION['captcha'] = simple_php_captcha( array(
    'min_length' => 5,
    'max_length' => 5,
    'backgrounds' => array(image.png', ...),
    'fonts' => array('font.ttf', ...),
    'characters' => 'ABCDEFGHJKLMNPRSTUVWXYZabcdefghjkmnprstuvwxyz23456789',
    'min_font_size' => 28,
    'max_font_size' => 28,
    'color' => '#666',
    'angle_min' => 0,
    'angle_max' => 10,
    'shadow' => true,
    'shadow_color' => '#fff',
    'shadow_offset_x' => -1,
    'shadow_offset_y' => 1
));
```